# using template match in xslt to select dynamic tags

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

i wish to use template match to select dynamic tags

The input xml has tags `<?PG 1?>,<?PG 2?>,<?PG 3?>`.....etc for page division

`<?PG` is constant but the numbers keeps on increasing.

i wish to use something like

```
       <xsl:template match="?PG*" >
    some conditions..
     </xsl:template>
```

how to i select the node musing template match

also there are many special character parameters in the input like & ndash; , & mdash; , & rsquo;

is there a way i can replace them with &#8211 for &ndash and similarly for others

sample input:

```
     <TXTBKBD>
     <?PG 1?>
     <DIVISIONA>
     <THD><HD>Preliminary Section: Materials</HD></THD>
     <BY>
     <PN><FN>Christopher</FN><SN>Womack</SN><DEG>PhD, FACSM</DEG>
      <ROLE>Section Editor</ROLE></PN>
      </BY>
      <?PG 2?>
      <CHAPTER CHAN="B01429413-DA1-C1" V="2006.2" REPLACE="NO">
      <CHSO>
      <THD><HNUM>Chapter 1</HNUM><HD>Functional Anatomy</HD></THD>
      <BY><PN><SN>&NA;</SN></PN></BY>
      </CHSO>
```

the xml is around 30 mb so its too big to put it here

on gaining the input as  i wish an output such as

```
   <a name="PG1"> </a><div class="pagenum"><div>P.1</div></div>
```

Comment: `<?PG 1?>`,`<?PG 2>` are actually 'processing-instructions'. You can write XSLT to match them, but to give a more precise answer it would help if you actually showed a small, but representative, sample of your XML, and the output you are expecting. Thanks!

Comment: and regarding the `&ndash;` etc. entities - you shouldn't need to do anything with these (assuming the original input document has a DTD that defines them correctly).  They will be resolved into their respective characters automatically when the document is parsed, and escaped as character references if necessary when you serialize the result (_if necessary_ - if you're writing out the result in an encoding like UTF-8 that can represent them natively then they won't be escaped because they don't need to be).

Comment: i am using utf-8 format, which format should i use as i do not wish to display them in the native format

Comment: It sound like you are asking two separate questions here! Both may be valid questions, but it might be worth asking a separate question about replacing the entities, if you can't work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards the tags `<?PG 1?>,<?PG 2?>,<?PG 3?>`, these are processing instructions. You can match them with the helpfully named "processing-instruction()" function

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
```

Or, if you wanted to be more specific, you could do this

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[name() = 'PG']">
```

For these templates to be called though, you will obviously need to be using **xsl:apply-templates** somewhere in your XSLT.

Having matched them, it is simple to get the name, with the **name()** function, and the value with **xsl:value-of**

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[name() = 'PG']">
   <a name="{name()}"> </a>
   <div class="pagenum">
      <div>P.<xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
   </div>
</xsl:template>
```

When this matches the `<?PG 1?>` processing instruction, the following is output

```
<a name="PG"/><div class="pagenum"><div>P.1</div></div>
```

Comment: Actually if the name of the processing instruction is known statically you can do `match="processing-instruction(PG)"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482511/special-characters-are-not-transformed-on-xslt-transformation    added as separate question